# implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' showing an error

Tags: java, android-studio, implementation

I have this problem in build.gradle this line is all in red 
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
Please what does that mean and how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify your error rather than just mentioning red line under the code. Hover above that red line and you will find the reason behind it.

Most probably the error should be "Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0".

Firstly Check that you have updated targetSdkVersion to 28

Generally, This message means that the package is not being found.

One way is to update all the dependency package that you are using to v28.

I was using:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
```

I changed it to :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
```

This should work.